# Parameters to uiAutomator test class

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am new to uiAutomator. I tried passing the parameters to method, it run but just ignores anything passed to it.
Just wondering whether we can pass any arguments to test class or test method in uiAutomator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789124/uiautomator-changing-variables/20985597#20985597)

You can send in parameters via command line:

```
adb shell am insrument -e <NAME> <VALUE> <package/runner>
```

You can access the value using the bundle that is available if you override the `onCreatemethod` of the InstrumentationTestRunner.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  value = (String) savedInstanceState.get("name");
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is posted twice and it's twice accepted wrong. Don't you really see the difference between **uiautomator** and **instrumentation** tests? OP is asking about black box testing via uiautomator and the right answer is provided below by @diptia

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a bit old but I just started working on a UIAutomator project and figured I would share what I found.

The original question is a little ambiguous.  It seems from the existing answers everyone assumed the question was about command line arguments/ startup arguments so I'm going to follow suit.

Neither of the answewrs worked well for what I was doing.  The first can be used I think, but its a bit overkill to over ride onCreate for such a simple task.  The second just didn't seem to work at all for me.  I believe it is missing some information.

Get parameters is a call from the arguments Bundle.  You need to get the from the instrumentation test.  You can do that in AndroidTest by calling to InstrumentationRegistry

```
Bundle testBundle = InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments();
```

Then you can make the get string call from that bundle.

```
testBundle.getString(key);
```

I'm not sure how to do this exactly from eclipse or android studio, but from command line you can then specify running your test with the following ADB call.

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.example.testApp.testappone.ExampleClass -e ParamKey 'your variable value' com.example.testApp.testappone.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Just to show a full example, if you make the adb call above you would then access the parameter with the following code.

```
@Test
public void FirstTest(){   
    Bundle testBundle = InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments();
    String paramValue = testBundle.getString("ParamKey");
}
```

I do want to note that you can make the adb call numerous ways so please don't get caught up in using instrument vs uiautomator.  The important part is you specify the parameter with -e key value.

sources:
[Android Junit runner - used to run UI automator projects](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html)

and

[Instrumentation documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html#getArguments())

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to call `onCreate` to get the passed argument values. When you pass parameters to the testcase using

`adb shell uiautomator runtest UiTest.jar -c package.name.ClassName -e stringKey stringValue`

wherever in the testcase you wish to access stringValue, use:

`String stringValue = getParams().getString("stringKey");`

Comment: Hey @diptia the command which you have is not working.. Does this works for you?? if yes please share how you have executed your command

Comment: the answer is right and should be accepted instead of current one.