# Set test mode on from UIAutomator

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-uiautomator

Is it possible to send messages from **UIAutomator** or adb to the application to be tested? I want to **set test mode on** to mock some data when running tests, but I want to make may code as little dirty as possible. When it's about unit testing it is rather easy, using just an additional parameter.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20985597/1387685) approach but it would require adding lots of fluff in my code to send the is_testing parameter from the Activity to the Fragment and then to elsewhere.

A different approach would be uploading some file that the app reads when starting, but this solution is pretty ugly, too...

Is there any **clean** way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just send an `Intent` to your app

$ adb shell am start

Check `am` help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a little bit more? Checking the help I cannot see the point in using this approach... I cannot see any option that allows me to say my app that it's running in test mode.